# ExceptWith in HashSet for complex types

Tags: c#, equals, hashset

I have HashSet of my custom class:

```
public class Vertex
{
    public string Name;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var vert = obj as Vertex;
        if (vert !=null)
        {
            return Name.Equals(vert.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And now I have tow hashsets

```
HashSet<Vertex> hashSet1 = new HashSet<Vertex>();

HashSet<Vertex> hashSet1 = new HashSet<Vertex>();
```

And now I'd like to have in hashSet1 only Vertexes that are not in hashSet2
So I use ExceptWith method

```
hashSet1.ExceptWith(hashSet2);
```

But this doesn't work.
I suppose that this doesn't work because I have complex type.
So the question is: is there some interface required to be implemented in Vertex class to make this thing work?
I know that while creation of HashSet I can pass a EqualityComparer but it seems to me that it would be more elegant to implement some comparing interface method in Vertex class.

Is it possible or I just doesn't understand sth?

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When overriding `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode`. `HashSet` (and other hashing structures like `Dictionary`) will first calculate a hash code for your objects to locate them in tne structure before comparing elements with `Equals`.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return StringComparer.InvariantCulture.GetHashCode(this.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to implement any interface (although [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)) is encouraged. When you create a hash-set without specifying an equality-comparer, it defaults to using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which asks the objects themselves to compare themselves to each other (special-casing null references).

However, in your case, your equality contract is broken since you haven't overriden `GetHashCode`. Here's how I would fix your type:

```
public class Vertex : IEquatable<Vertex>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Vertex(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return StringComparer.InvariantCulture.GetHashCode(Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Vertex);
    }

    public bool Equals(Vertex obj)
    {
        return obj != null && StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals(Name, obj.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind overriding the `.GetHashCode()`too?

Here's the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden).

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `GetHashCode` with `Equals` overriding.

[Object.Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx):

> Types that override Equals(Object) must also override GetHashCode; otherwise, hash tables might not work correctly.